# Geocoding an address and using the lat / long as variables in JSON to submit to database

Tags: json, geocoding

I am fairly new to web design, and I have set myself a right task. I am trying to use Google Geocoder to code an address (stored in 5 seperate inputs - Address1, Address2, 3, 4, PostCode), then I need to use the Lat/Long results as variables in a JSON.php to add the Lat/Long to a database.

I have the form built, and have the JSON set up to deliver the inputs to the DB. I have also used geocoding script from the google API.

My question is how can I use the google Geocoder to deliver Lat/Long results, and then store them as a variable that I can use in my seperate JSON.php.

My code, at the moment is a fairly standard JSON.php, and the standard google geocode code.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Are you showing a map? It's against Google's TOS to use the geocoding service without showing a map on your webpage. (just a precautionary note -- a few weeks ago a large number of people reported access issues all of a sudden because Google did some "clean up") -- good thing to consider as you enter the web design world!

Comment: I will be using the Google map to display locations if a user decides to use that functionality... if i can ever get the lat / long into the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do one of two things... or three or four, but these are the most likely couple of options:

1. Use Javascript to get the lat/lon before the user submits the form, like as they type enough of the address, and populate `input type="hidden"` fields in your form which are then transferred to PHP on form submit.
2. Use PHP to query the geocoder and get the lat/lon after form submit then put the results in the database directly.

And have you considered verifying the address to make sure it's correct before geocoding it? Google has a tendency to return approximated results even if the address isn't real... (which is sometimes handy, but sometimes a bother).

Comment: Thanks Matt! I like the sound of option 1 - its close to what I am doing with the other inputs (to get them into the DB), but I'm afraid to say I would need a little more guidance... How would I get the Lat/Long into those fields from the geocoding code?

Comment: The easiest way might be to use Javascript's `getElementsByName` function, like: `document.getElementsByName("latitude")[0].value` will get the value of `<input type="hidden" name="latitude">` -- and I think you can also assign a value to it this way.

Comment: I have much to learn - I am trying to build this into my code, but I cant get the document.getelementsbyname bit to work. Do you know if this will work if the element is in a jquery overlay?

Comment: Yeah, you can do: `$('input[name=latitude]').val(results.lat);` *or something like that* to populate the field with that value.